# how to choose right SFP 1000BASE-T transceiver?

Tags: networking, latency

I want to connect [SFN7122F](http://www.solarflare.com/Content/UserFiles/Documents/Solarflare_SFN7122F_10GbE_Adapter_Brief.pdf) network card to 1000BASE-T (1 GB cooper Ethernet).
I've found a lot of transceiver and I don't understand how should I choose one:

- http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/3742795
- http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10213506
- http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/3872903

If I can use any of these transceivers? What is the difference between them? What is the average latency of the transceiver?

Comment: I wouldn't use any of those, drop Solarflare an email asking for a copy of their supported-SFPs.

Comment: why hp to produce so many similar adapters? they must have some difference..

Comment: You can ask HP. But I wouldn't even use an HP adapter for this.

Comment: No, me neither, what's wrong with a cheapo Intel card without SFP?

Comment: @Chopper3 He's trying to use UDP kernel bypass with [Solarflare's Open Onload](http://www.openonload.org). People normally do this with 10GbE (because it is faster, even at lower throughputs), but most environments have a switch in place.

Comment: The part numbers differ because the transceivers are meant to be used with different switch types. See below.

Comment: solarflare supported SFP's are here http://www.solarflare.com/Transceivers-and-Cables but I don't understand if they supposed to be connected to network card directly, or they can be connected to switches only? and what to connect to network card, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be much of a difference between the HP SFP+ copper adapters you listed, but they seem to have different purposes.

The first is meant for use with [HP Virtual Connect Bladeserver](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/bladesystem/virtual-connect/index.aspx) networking modules. The second is meant for [HP B-Series storage switches](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/switches/index.html#!facet=B-series). The third is general use and meant for HP ProCurve switches.

You can generally use most Copper SFP adapters. I've usually used generic or [Finisar transceivers](http://www.finisar.com/products/optical-modules/sfp/FCLF852xP2BTL) with Solarflare gear. I've also used Arista's adapters.

Comment: do you know which one is better to use with HP 570SFP+ ? why different hardware require different modules? why they have different price? i don't understand that. for example I can use Ethernet cable to connect any ethernet devices, i don't need better, more expanive cable to connect more expensive PC.

Comment: @javapowered For compatibility, consult the [vendor's documentation](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04123188). But why would you want a 1GB transceiver in a 10GB NIC? Other than that, modules will have different prices mainly due to support cost coverage. An SFP module plugged into a switch is covered by the same warranty as the base unit - which happens to be "lifetime" for switches. In a HP server system it is covered by the server's warranty and support contract. If you are not using HP systems and switches, you probably would not be able to make use of that, though.

Comment: i need 10Gb card to use OpenOnload or VMA for better latency. But I can't use 10 Gbit network because my stock exchange ask a lot of $$$ for 10Gb, but 1 Gb is much more cheaper